# How to read the value of dropdown list in excel and add to a datatable C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledbconnection

Hello i am facing the following problem:
I have an excel file that has some cells with dropdown list. I am trying to read the excel and add it to datatable in order to manipulate the data. I have manage to read the excel and add it to datable BUT my method reads all the values that the cells with dropdownlist have, it doesnt read only the one that is selected. For example i gave a cell with three values (1,2,3) and the cell has as selected the value 1. My method reads the excel and adds to the datatable all the values in different rows. So it adds 1,2,3.
You can see my code below:

```
    protected void ddlReviewStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    string finalDate = date.Replace("/", "");
    string fileName = "test.xlsx";

    DropDownList ddlReviewStatus = sender as DropDownList;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddlReviewStatus.NamingContainer;
    string companyName = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblCompName")).Text;

    string filePath = ReportTemplatesPath + "\\" + companyName + "\\" + finalDate + "\\" + fileName;

    if (ddlReviewStatus.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper() == "DONE")
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        string conStr = "";
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                         .ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                          .ConnectionString;
                break;
        }

        conStr = String.Format(conStr, filePath,"Yes");
        OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

        //Get the name of First Sheet
        connExcel.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSchema;
        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        connExcel.Close();

        connExcel.Open();
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        oda.Fill(dt);
        connExcel.Close();

        //Bind Data to GridView
        GridView1.Caption = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```